# C# Start a new MailTo Process and HTML URL Encoding

Tags: c#, process, url-encoding, mailto, processstartinfo

I have created a new MailTo extension method for the Process class which just fills the Process with a new ProcessStartinfo which contains the required mailto arguments. I have created a method called FormatMailToArgument (Right at the end) which converts control characters to their Url Encoded equivelants and have tested this and it works but is there a better way of doing this?

```
/// <summary>
/// <see cref="Process"/> extension methods.
/// </summary>
public static class Processes
{
    #region MailTo

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the process with mailto <see cref="ProcessStartInfo"/>. You may leave any
    /// argument as <c>null</c> if not needed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="process">The process.</param>
    /// <param name="mailMessage">The mail message.</param>
    public static void MailTo(this Process process, MailMessage mailMessage)
    {
        MailTo(
            process,
            mailMessage.To.ToDelimetedString(),
            mailMessage.CC.ToDelimetedString(),
            mailMessage.Bcc.ToDelimetedString(),
            mailMessage.Subject,
            mailMessage.Body);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the process with mailto <see cref="ProcessStartInfo"/>. You may leave any
    /// argument as <c>null</c> if not needed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="process">The process.</param>
    /// <param name="to">To email addresses.</param>
    public static void MailTo(this Process process, IEnumerable<string> to)
    {
        MailTo(
            process,
            to.ToDelimetedString(Character.SemiColon),
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the process with mailto <see cref="ProcessStartInfo"/>. You may leave any
    /// argument as <c>null</c> if not needed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="process">The process.</param>
    /// <param name="to">To email addresses.</param>
    /// <param name="subject">The email subject.</param>
    public static void MailTo(this Process process, IEnumerable<string> to, string subject)
    {
        MailTo(
            process,
            to.ToDelimetedString(Character.SemiColon),
            null,
            null,
            subject,
            null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the process with mailto <see cref="ProcessStartInfo"/>. You may leave any
    /// argument as <c>null</c> if not needed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="process">The process.</param>
    /// <param name="to">To email addresses.</param>
    /// <param name="subject">The email subject.</param>
    /// <param name="body">The email body.</param>
    public static void MailTo(
        this Process process,
        IEnumerable<string> to,
        string subject,
        string body)
    {
        MailTo(
            process,
            to.ToDelimetedString(Character.SemiColon),
            null,
            null,
            subject,
            body);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the process with mailto <see cref="ProcessStartInfo"/>. You may leave any
    /// argument as <c>null</c> if not needed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="process">The process.</param>
    /// <param name="to">To email addresses.</param>
    /// <param name="cc">The Cc email addresses.</param>
    /// <param name="subject">The email subject.</param>
    /// <param name="body">The email body.</param>
    public static void MailTo(
        this Process process,
        IEnumerable<string> to,
        IEnumerable<string> cc,
        string subject,
        string body)
    {
        MailTo(
            process,
            to.ToDelimetedString(Character.SemiColon),
            cc.ToDelimetedString(Character.SemiColon),
            null,
            subject,
            body);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the process with mailto <see cref="ProcessStartInfo"/>. You may leave any 
    /// argument as <c>null</c> if not needed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="process">The process.</param>
    /// <param name="to">To email addresses.</param>
    /// <param name="cc">The Cc email addresses.</param>
    /// <param name="bcc">The Bcc email addresses.</param>
    /// <param name="subject">The email subject.</param>
    /// <param name="body">The email body.</param>
    public static void MailTo(
        this Process process,
        IEnumerable<string> to,
        IEnumerable<string> cc,
        IEnumerable<string> bcc,
        string subject,
        string body)
    {
        MailTo(
            process,
            (to == null) ? null : to.ToDelimetedString(Character.SemiColon),
            (cc == null) ? null : cc.ToDelimetedString(Character.SemiColon),
            (bcc == null) ? null : bcc.ToDelimetedString(Character.SemiColon),
            subject,
            body);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the process with mailto <see cref="ProcessStartInfo"/>. You may leave any
    /// argument as <c>null</c> if not needed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="process">The process.</param>
    /// <param name="to">To email addresses.</param>
    /// <param name="cc">The Cc email addresses.</param>
    /// <param name="bcc">The Bcc email addresses.</param>
    /// <param name="subject">The email subject.</param>
    /// <param name="body">The email body.</param>
    /// <param name="attachmentPath">The attachment file path.</param>
    public static void MailTo(
        this Process process,
        IEnumerable<string> to,
        IEnumerable<string> cc,
        IEnumerable<string> bcc,
        string subject,
        string body,
        string attachmentPath)
    {
        MailTo(
            process,
            (to == null) ? null : to.ToDelimetedString(Character.SemiColon),
            (cc == null) ? null : cc.ToDelimetedString(Character.SemiColon),
            (bcc == null) ? null : bcc.ToDelimetedString(Character.SemiColon),
            subject,
            body,
            attachmentPath);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the process with mailto <see cref="ProcessStartInfo"/>. You may leave any 
    /// argument as <c>null</c> if not needed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="process">The process.</param>
    /// <param name="to">To email addresses delimeted by a semi-colon.</param>
    /// <param name="cc">The Cc email addresses delimeted by a semi-colon.</param>
    /// <param name="bcc">The Bcc email addresses delimeted by a semi-colon.</param>
    /// <param name="subject">The email subject.</param>
    /// <param name="body">The email body.</param>
    public static void MailTo(this Process process, string to, string cc, string bcc, string subject, string body)
    {
        MailTo(process, to, cc, bcc, subject, body, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the process with mailto <see cref="ProcessStartInfo"/>. You may leave any
    /// argument as <c>null</c> if not needed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="process">The process.</param>
    /// <param name="to">To email addresses delimeted by a semi-colon.</param>
    /// <param name="cc">The Cc email addresses delimeted by a semi-colon.</param>
    /// <param name="bcc">The Bcc email addresses delimeted by a semi-colon.</param>
    /// <param name="subject">The email subject.</param>
    /// <param name="body">The email body.</param>
    /// <param name="attachmentPath">The attachment file path. Note: this will not work in some 
    /// email applications.</param>
    public static void MailTo(
        this Process process,
        string to,
        string cc,
        string bcc,
        string subject,
        string body,
        string attachmentPath)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.Append(Uri.UriSchemeMailto + Character.Colon);
        stringBuilder.Append(FormatMailToArgument(to));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cc) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(bcc) ||
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(subject) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(body) ||
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachmentPath))
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(Character.Question);

            List<string> arguments = new List<string>();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subject))
            {
                arguments.Add("subject=" + FormatMailToArgument(subject));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
            {
                arguments.Add("body=" + FormatMailToArgument(body));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cc))
            {
                arguments.Add("CC=" + FormatMailToArgument(cc));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bcc))
            {
                arguments.Add("BCC=" + FormatMailToArgument(bcc));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachmentPath))
            {
                arguments.Add("attachment=" + FormatMailToArgument(attachmentPath));
            }

            stringBuilder.Append(arguments.ToDelimetedString(Character.Ampersand));
        }

        process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(stringBuilder.ToString());
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Formats the mailto argument. Converts <![CDATA['%', '&', ' ', '?', '\t', '\n']]> to their 
    /// hexadecimal representation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="argument">The argument.</param>
    /// <returns>The formatted argument.</returns>
    private static string FormatMailToArgument(string argument)
    {
        return argument.
            Replace(Character.Percent.ToString(), "%25").
            Replace(Character.Ampersand.ToString(), "%26").
            Replace(Character.Colon.ToString(), "%3A").
            Replace(Character.HorizontalTab.ToString(), "%0D").
            Replace(Character.NewLine.ToString(), "%0A").
            Replace(Character.Question.ToString(), "%3F").
            Replace(Character.Quote.ToString(), "%22").
            Replace(Character.Space.ToString(), "%20");
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you mean is there are more efficient way to escape your email addresses then yes you could use the System.Uri class.

```
string escapedAddress = Uri.EscapeUriString("mailto:joe blogg's\r\n@mail.com");
Console.WriteLine(escapedAddress);
```

Output:

```
mailto:joe%20blogg's%0D%0A@mail.com
```

You'll notice in my example the single quote character doesn't get escaped but that's because it's not required to be in email addresses.

As far as the general approach you have used I don't see why you would add an extension method to the Process class. To send an email and have all the address escaping. attachments, server authentication etc. etc. taken care of why not just use the  [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) classes?

Comment: Is System.Net.Mail what you are looking for?

Comment: I wanted to open a new outlook mail message without going through all the hassle of messing around with Outlook interops and Redemption. This has the added advantage of working with any mail client and is relatively simple code.

Comment: Tried using Uri.EscapeUriString with the body:
" !""#$25&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ € ‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹Œ Ž  ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œ žŸ ¡¢£ ¥|§¨©ª«¬¯®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»&#1

Comment: Using my code all characters come out correctly. Is my test complete though? I would prefer to use something which I can rely on.

Comment: Using Uri.EscapeDataString helped but many of the symbol characters were garbled.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get why you would use extension methods on the Process class for mail functionality? Do you want to open Outlook emails from file? You don't need to escape the body of an email there's no limit on which characters can go into it except for <CRLF>.<CRLF>.

Comment: I totally agree with sipwiz on the fact that you should not use extension methods here. You are giving the mailing functionalities to the wrong object. Extension methods must be used as an extension to the current class functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

As documented in is [this official link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring(v=vs.110).aspx), the `EscapeUriString` method assumes that `stringToEscape` parameter has no escape sequences in it.

This method is perfect for escaping Uris, but be careful because the target string is a `mailto:` line that can contain many parameters (not only subject, body, ...), obviously separated each one with some escape characters...like *&* and *?*.

So, in my tests with Windows Store Apps with text taken from @anon comment, that string will not be fully escaped using *just* `Uri.EscapeUriString()` method, because it contains the escape sequence *&*.

You will need an extra manual escape to get the whole string be passed as parameter in a `mailto:` Uri:

```
Uri.EscapeUriString(stringToEscape).Replace("&", "%26");
```